# How to query for Double with Spring JDBC template query

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

How do one query for a double with the Spring JDBC temple?

For example:

```
public double getAverageScore() {
    return jdbctemplate.queryFor???("select avg(score) from test");
}
```

There are queryForInt and queryForLong, but no queryForDouble

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but [queryForObject](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject) with `Double.class` as the last parameter might work.

```
public double getAverageScore() {
    return jdbctemplate.queryForObject("select avg(score) from test", Double.class);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
public double getAverageScore() {
    return jdbctemplate.queryForObject("select avg(score) from test", Double.class);
}
```

Comment: Out of topic, just interesting why Spring have no convenience method for Double and Long, when there is one for Int and Long

Answer (score 2):

```
public Double avgByCampo(Long param) {
   return simpleJdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT avg(t.campo) FROM table t where t.id_campo = ?", Double.class, param);
}
```